# Why createcontainer meteor call in React-Native display stack navigator header?

Tags: meteor, react-native, react-navigation

I am using StackNavigator from 'react-navigation' to control navigation and Meteor to fetch data. In order to remove default navigation header, I wrote this
`static navigationOptions = { header: null};`. It works fine with static data. But whenever I am calling `createContainer()` function to collect data, that component displays default white header above my custom header. Can anyone show me what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it working by moving static navigationOptions out of the class.
For example you can save created container in variable

```
const container = createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('somedata')
    return {
    data: Meteor.data()
  }
}, YourClass)
```

and attach navigationOptions to it:

```
 container.navigationOptions = { header: null}
```

and export that new container with attached navigationOptions

```
export default container
```